# Replicating a dedication plate's effects in TeX

Tags: tikz-pgf

Looking at old books on design and typography  archive.org, I came across this lovely dedication plate created by hand engraving (sorry for the poor quality but this was the best available scan):

[image]

Specifically, is there a way to mold the black and white around the letters as is done with the "To H" and the "y" at the end of "Majesty"?  Additionally, is there a way to integrate the swashes with the ornaments, as is done here?

I think this is a TikZ problem, but I am way out of my depth...

Comment: Sure that the black areas in "to H" are by design? It seems like a scanned image that has been defectively vectorized, and it is just an artifact of the vectorial image. Note that the pattern of the another black areas have not -sense at all.

Comment: Even if this is something that you can mimic in Ti*k*Z, what Fran said is right. It's just a bad scanning from [white on black image](https://thumbs.worthpoint.com/zoom/images3/1/0913/06/nonesuch-press-1953-volumes_1_fd4a4e7faf258ca30bcb950b2c2f7e36.jpg).

Comment: @SebGlav mea culpa and well spotted! I might just delete the question because it's not useful to anyone.  I am slightly ashamed that I confused defective scans for art, but live and learn

Comment: No problem, that could be confusing ;)